# Bootstrap doesn't dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying but doens't work I don't know.

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a href="#" class="brand">MyTry</a>

        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a class="active" href="#">..</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">..</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <span class=" icon-search"></span>
                    <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text input">
                    </form>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>   
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't seeing the error. Just doesn't work dropdown system. E.g. adding to inside

```
<li><a href="#">foo-bar</a></li>
```

still doesn't work.

How we do solve?
Thank you for you interest.

Good works..

Comment: have you added bootstrap.css?

Answer (score 1):

You should include `jquery` and `bootstrap` js files.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For any of bootstraps dropdowns, animation etc. To work you have to include the

> **bootstrap.js**

file.

**Here you have a fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/BH9g9/

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a href="#" class="brand">MyTry</a>

        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a class="active" href="#">..</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">..</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <span class=" icon-search"></span>
                    <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text input">
                    </form>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>   
    </div>
</div>
```

There is nothing wrong with ur code. Other than the missing javascript include.